# Stream MP3 from blob storage to client via Azure Function with V1 runtime

Tags: c#, http, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to stream files from blob storage through a HTTP-triggered Azure Function so I can gather some metrics about downloads, but I haven't been able to get the actual streaming working correctly. Here's what I've managed to get working so far:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string inputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, inputBlob);
}
```

With `function.json` looking like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "path": "my-container/sample-file.mp3",
      "connection": "<appsetting>",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This **almost** seems to work, but it doesn't return the correct `Content-Type` header (it should be `audio/mpeg` but appears as `application/xml; charset=utf-8`), and for some reason, the `Content-Length` of the response is almost three times bigger than expected.

Comment: Shouldn't you just redirect the user to the blob URL (with maybe a SAS appended if not everything is supposed to be public)? Why are you man in the middling the content if all you care about is telemetry? Right now your function has to fire every time the browser requests a new chunk of that audio. Also, watch out for `Accept-Ranges` (partial requests), seeking won't work by default, you'll need to amend the storage account configuration a little bit. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582841/audio-tag-not-working-correctly-when-playing-an-mp3-stored-as-azure-blob-in-chro).

Comment: @evilSnobu - I'm also generating a podcast feed so that I can have the mp3s available through the iPhone Podcasts app. Using a 302 redirect causes each episode to be opened in Safari when they're played, rather than natively within the app. Or is there a different HTTP status code that might work?

Comment: Try HTTP 301, 303, 308. There should be some guidance for this specific scenario published by Apple. If you end up unable to redirect, use the blob URL directly and enable storage analytics logging to get some telemetry - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging. Reverse proxying through the function is just putting money on the floor and setting it on fire.

Comment: Tried all the 3xx codes available in the HttpStatusCode enum and didn't have any success... I haven't been able to find any docs from Apple, either. The original solution was actually to use blob logs, which worked reasonably well except that we need to gather some user-specific metrics (each user has their own unique endpoint). Looks like we might be out of luck though... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now I will show you how to download files from Azure blob Storage to your local:
1. make sure you have file in the azure blob storage.

[image]

2.Code.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace DownloadFileV1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=bowmanimagestorage02;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference("images");
            container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("grass.jpg");
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\bowmanzh\Downloads\download1.jpg"))
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "");
        }
    }
}
```

3.send request.

Then you can get the files in the cloud locally. I used the image, but even the video or music files are no problem.

[image]
[image]

If you have more issues, please let me know.

Comment: What happens if you seek midway through an MP3 file, does this solution present `Accept-Ranges` and deliver the audio chunk to the browser or is it progressive download or bust?

Comment: @evilSnobu This method transfers the file stream. What is received last depends on what file you are transferring. It does not involve the encoding of the file.